How to connect the frontend and backend in Amplify?
I've deployed 2 separated repositories for the frontend and backend in Amplify. I've set it up my custom domain in the frontend. When I access to the domain it will display the frontend but the backend data is not there. Do I need to connect the backend to the frontend? I don't know how or what to do. I'm also getting an error: GET https://MY_DOMAIN/api/MY_API/ 404 (Not Found) I could provide more information if needed. Thanks.
Tools:
React Vite, Express, Amplify

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
